# BucketNotEmpty - 409 Conflict is not working

Tags: amazon-s3

As per the S3 documentation, The bucket you tried to delete is not empty it should through 409 conflict error.  But through S3 web console, im able to delete the S3 bucket which is not empty.

Does this mean, 409 error code is only applicable only for API's not from console. I couldnt find the exact definition on this.

Comment: You need to show us your request and buckets, maybe you tried to delete the wrong one?

Comment: Im able to delete the s3 bucket through console which is not empty.    But documentation on 409 conflict is conflicting

Comment: Sorry I don't understand a word you write.